# Getting the files from Azure Blob and sending them in one email

Tags: azure, automation, azure-logic-apps

I have a setup that is exporting all the json files generated from an API sent to an email address upon a request sent to a shared mailbox, but the thing is that currently logic app is sending out separate emails, one json per email, so it's 7 emails in my case.

My final solution would be sending all the json files in one email. Have tried to figure out the connector methods, but seems that I cannot find that out. Tried to Google of course, but no luck.
Would really appreciate any help!

Current setup looks like this:

Azure Logic App 1:
[image: azure logic app 1]

Azure Logic App 2:
[image: azure logic app 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build an array of all of the attachments outside of the loop.

This is the flow I tested with ...

[image: Flow]

... the two important points are:

#### Construct an Attachments Array

As you can see, I've declared a variable at the top `Attachments` of type `Array`.

Get your blobs and then loop over each one of them.

Within the loop, get the contents of the blob and then add an object to the array that looks like the following JSON structure ...

[image: For Each]

This is the `Peek Code` of the array item, noting that I am encoding the content as `base64` ...

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "name": "Attachments",
        "value": {
            "ContentBytes": "@{base64(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))}",
            "Name": "@{items('For_Each_Blob')?['DisplayName']}"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Send the Email

Now, when you send the email, refer to the array as the contents of the `Attachments` parameter.

[image: Send Email]

That should get the job done for you, it worked for me.

Comment: Amazing! All went well and I did got how this works. Now I can build more stuff :) Thanks Julian and thanks Skin for an extended explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the output of the GetBlob Content to an array or adding it into a string? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values#initialize-variable and then using this variable to create the email body?

Comment: Hi Julian. I have tried, but when iterating it does not add all to the var, it just adds the last iteration. Also, the json output for each file is in 40 lines each, with configuration data and sending that in one text wall would not be an option. Please, correct if I am wrong here.

Comment: I think in this case, an Azure Function would be better as it might fits your needs better