# Azure Logic apps how to send an email with multiple attachments just ONE time

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have notice that several people has struggled with the almost same issue as me. In my case I do get all the files from a storage blog in an email. My issue is that logic apps sends that email as many time as the number of attachments.

I do think that there is an easy solution for this problem although I dind't find then.
Please check the workflow:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your great help.
Regards, NT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the files from Azure Blob and sending them in one email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73605324/getting-the-files-from-azure-blob-and-sending-them-in-one-email)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I followed below process, and I got expected results as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Results:

[image]

I have got all files in one email

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems your setup is like mine unless the trigger.  By that reason I suspect that trigger I use ( When a blob is added or modified) is triggered each time a new blob (file) is modified or moved to the container. Since I add three files I get three emails ... Do you know if there is a possibility to trigger this trigger just one time independently of how many files are added ?

Comment: Yeah you can use this trigger as first step, then the rest of your steps in logic app., This way you can trigger once irrespective of when a file is added. Or else use recurrence trigger daily once, so that you can trigger this flow daily once irrespective of blob created.