# How to send an email from a query result having more than one line

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to send emails via a sql query that contains multiple lines. What is the best way to combine them into a batch or a group so that it doesn't send me hundreds of emails?

So for example the query returns 100 rows and the last two columns are person name and email. They are of course duplicated all the way down from 1-100. So I would like to send those 100 rows to said person via their email address.

I have tested on a single line for different people, seem to work perfectly, although the problem occurs when there is multiple lines for each person (grouped by diff email address).

This is pretty straight forward in SSRS, but at the moment that is not an option.

Comment: please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906042/azure-logic-apps-how-to-send-an-email-with-multiple-attachments-just-one-time) you send rows into a file then send to a mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a table with duplicates and unique records.

[image]

- Created logic app as shown below:

[image]

- In Execute query action, written sql query as:

```
SELECT Name,Email, COUNT (*) FROM [dbo].[Persons] GROUP BY Name,Email HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[image]

[image]
This will fetch duplicate records from table.

- In send email action, given `'To'` address from the execute query result action as shown below:

[image]

```
body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1'][0]?['Email']
```

[image]

**Output Email:**

[image]