# getting information from specific runs of logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have logic apps running in azure.
We can query some details of past runs in azure log analytics.

Log analytics does not seem to contain any of the output from each task in the logic app, even though i can see this in the logic app history.

Is there a way to query the data/payloads/output from each task in the logic app?

Comment: Are you using tracked properties in the logic app? Tracked properties always shows up in the log analytics workspace -> Azure diagnostics, if you have configured your logic app to send info to your log analytics workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get logs of Logic apps, I have followed below process:

Firstly, open your Log analytics workspace
In general tab open workspace summary as below:
[image]

then click on add as below:

[image]

Then click on Logic apps managemnet(preview):

[image]

The click on create:

[image]

Then give details and click on create:

[image]

Then open your created as below:

[image]

Then, I have created a workflow in logic app and then I opened Diagnostic settings as below:

[image]

Then give important details as below:

[image]

open your Log analytics workspace
In general tab open workspace summary as below:

[image]

Then you will get output as below:

[image]

When you click on chart you will get information like below:
[image]

If you click on row of LogicApp(table in above display)
[image]

Alternatively in work summary in log analytics, click on logs and then You can the below kql query to get logs and you can export it using export option as below:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName has "workflowRunCompleted"
```

[image]

You can also send a email of payload (example [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906042/azure-logic-apps-how-to-send-an-email-with-multiple-attachments-just-one-time/73908242#73908242)) to check your runs or you can create an alert on each run in logicapp.

Comment: Thanks. this does not provide the payload of a task in the logic app.
e.g. i have an api call that returns xml. If i look in the logic app history and view a specific run, i can see the exact xml returned by that task. I can go right back for months. This data is not visible in the log analytics tables however. I need to find runs where the body returned by that web task contains a specific value. Was hoping to do this in log analytics with kusto.

Comment: AFAIK, in logs you will not able to get the raw inputs or raw outputs which we get in every run, Over here only the details of run are showed as in the image I provided