# How to add logs in log analytics in azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I am following this tutorial and I am also able to add the logic app logs into azure log analytics but the problem is that logic analytics for logic apps is still in preview mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics

I have few question regarding this.

- should I use it for logging as it is still in preview mode.
- If not what other options do I have to logs data in azure monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview mode is mode where full-fledged features are not available. This type of modes is provided to give feedbacks to improve it better.

If you ask me about to use it or not, I usually use it and i get desired results, and it works fine for me [Example-Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74069284/getting-information-from-specific-runs-of-logic-apps/74093238#74093238).

[image]

The other way I monitor logs is by using below process:
So firstly, I send logs to Log analytics workspace and then, I created another logic apps and get logs by below process:

[image]
[image]

Another way is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-monitoring-tracking-queries) to log Logs of Azure Logic Apps.