# How to query the status of the logic app in Azure using KQL queries

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kql, azure-diagnostics

AS I mentioned in the title. I am trying to get the Status of the LogicApps available in my subscription. For that am using the below query.

KQL:

```
AzureDiagnostics 
| where type == "AzureActivity" 
| where ResourceResource == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC/workflows" 
| project LogicAppName, Status = tostring(todynamic(tostring(parse_json(Properties).state)).value) | summarize Enabled = countif(Status == "Enabled"), Disabled = countif(Status == "Disabled") by LogicAppName
```

But AzureDiagnostics does not have the access to logic app properties it seems. also found the below kql query that's also not worked as I didn't find any 'resources' as mentioned in the query

```
resources 
| where type == "microsoft.logic/workflows"
| extend state = properties.state 
| extend trigger = properties.definition.triggers 
| extend createdTime = properties.createdTime 
| extend changedTime = properties.changedTime 
| extend connections = properties.parameters.$connections.value 
| project name, createdTime, changedTime, state, subscriptionId, connections, location, resourceGroup
```

can somebody help me to fix it .

Answer (score 0):

> How to query the status of the logic app in Azure using KQL queries

You can log the status, but for that you need to send your logs of all logic apps to Log analytics workspace as below and then Kql query:

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results and followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74093238/17623802) and [Microsoft-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-workflows-collect-diagnostic-data?tabs=consumption).:

Firstly type workspace summary in Log analytics workspace as below:

[image]

Then click on Logic Apps Managemnet(Preview):

[image]

Then click on create and add name of the workspace:

[image]

Then go to the resource that is created.

Now the logic app which is created and have logs open that, In that click on Diagnostic settings and add it as below:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Then wait for sometime for the logs to get into Log analytics workspace and then open your log analytics workspace and use the below Kql  query to the status of workflow:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName contains "workflowRun"
```

[image]

[image]

So, You need to send logs of all Logic apps to Log analytic workspace and then use the Kql query.