# Logic App Terminate does not complate the workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I Have a Logic App with a Terminate statement in a try catch block.

[image]

I am also using the monitoring solution LogicAppsManagement https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.LogicAppsManagement?tab=Overview

Workflows that fail using the terminate action appear as failed in the run history. This is as expected.

[image]

However they do not appear in as "Failed" in the Log Analytics Workspace when I run the follwing query:

```
// Logic App execution distribution by status 
// Completed executions by workflow,status and error. 
//logic app execution status summary
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName has "workflowRunCompleted"
| summarize dcount(resource_runId_s) by resource_workflowName_s, status_s, error_code_s
| project LogicAppName = resource_workflowName_s , NumberOfExecutions = dcount_resource_runId_s , RunStatus = status_s , Error = error_code_s
```

I expect that I see the same results as in run history of a logic app

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly set up the `Logic Apps Management(Preview)` to get the logs. Refer to this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77389943/how-to-query-the-status-of-the-logic-app-in-azure-using-kql-queries) to configure **Logic Apps Management(Preview)**. Here I am also using **Terminate** action inside **Scope** . For failed requests, I am getting failed runs as shown below-

[image]

I have used the below query and got the expected output.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC"
| where OperationName contains "workflowRunCompleted"
| summarize dcount(resource_runId_s) by resource_workflowName_s, status_s, code_s
| project LogicAppName = resource_workflowName_s , NumberOfExecutions = dcount_resource_runId_s , RunStatus = status_s , Error = code_s
```

**Output**-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I double checked my logs settings and they are as suggested. I can see the succeed and running ones but not the failed oned.  When i remove line number 3 in your query. I get results. So it seems that my workflows never complete. Is there a way to force this in a logic app?

Comment: @maxgaulhofer you want to force complete the logic app?